# I'm having trouble with this function call or expression error

Tags: reactjs, jsx

When I tried to run the program, I received an error saying this 'Line 5:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions' on 'width: 80%'. Can someone help me fix this?

```
import {Box, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow, Typography, styled} from '@mui/material';

const Component = styled(Box)
    'width: 80%'

const Users = () => {

    return (
        <Component>
            <Typography variant="h4">Users</Typography>
            <Box>
                <Table>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Id</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Email</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Phone</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Salary</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Age</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Remove Entry</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>101</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Code for Interview</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>codeforinterview@gmail.com</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>9998887765</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>22000</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>24</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Remove</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </Box>
        </Component>
    )
}

export default Users;
```

Comment: Your styled component expression needs to use backticks, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your styled component expression needs to use backticks (`), not single quotes ('):

```js
const Component = styled(Box)`
  width: 80%
`
```

It's a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).